# How to calculate and return a JSON object with all the days of a selected month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, datetime

I am building an Rails 5 app.
In this app I got Timereport objects.

I want to return ALL days from a selected month and add Timereport object data (hours) for the days that got them and empty for the others even if they are "empty".

This is an example JSON response.

```
[
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-01", "ends_at": "2017-08-01", hours: 1},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-02", "ends_at": "2017-08-02", hours: 2},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-03", "ends_at": "2017-08-03", hours: 5},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-04", "ends_at": "2017-08-04", hours: 3},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-05", "ends_at": "2017-08-05", hours: 4},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-06", "ends_at": "2017-08-06", hours: 5},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-07", "ends_at": "2017-08-07", hours: 6},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-08", "ends_at": "2017-08-08", hours: 3},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-09", "ends_at": "2017-08-09", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-10", "ends_at": "2017-08-10", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-11", "ends_at": "2017-08-11", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-12", "ends_at": "2017-08-12", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-13", "ends_at": "2017-08-13", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-14", "ends_at": "2017-08-14", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-15", "ends_at": "2017-08-15", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-16", "ends_at": "2017-08-16", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-17", "ends_at": "2017-08-17", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-18", "ends_at": "2017-08-18", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-19", "ends_at": "2017-08-19", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-20", "ends_at": "2017-08-20", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-21", "ends_at": "2017-08-21", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-22", "ends_at": "2017-08-22", hours: 3},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-23", "ends_at": "2017-08-23", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-24", "ends_at": "2017-08-24", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-25", "ends_at": "2017-08-25", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-26", "ends_at": "2017-08-26", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-27", "ends_at": "2017-08-27", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-28", "ends_at": "2017-08-28", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-29", "ends_at": "2017-08-29", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-30", "ends_at": "2017-08-30", hours: nil},
    {"starts_at": "2017-08-31", "ends_at": "2017-08-31", hours: nil}
]
```

I print out dates like this

```
start_date = Date.today.at_beginning_of_month
end_date = Date.today.at_end_of_month

start_date.upto(end_date) do |date|
    puts date
end
```

But I need to find a good query to check which days that got a Timereport object and print it for that day.

I know I can make a query for each day but there sure must be a query where I can get all Timereports for the selected month and then iterate over them for each day in the above loop. One query for each day feels wrong.

**Update**

*I do this*

```
start_date = Date.today.at_beginning_of_month
        end_date = Date.today.at_end_of_month
        array = []
        start_date.upto(end_date) do |date|
            array << {"display_weekday" => date.strftime("%A"), "display_date" => date, "starts_at_date" => date, "starts_at_time" => "07:00", "ends_at_date" => "#{date} 17:00", "ends_at_time" => "17:00", "pause" => ""}
        end 
        render json: array.to_json
```

**To produce this:**

```
[
{
"display_weekday": "Tuesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-01",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-01",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-01 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Wednesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-02",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-02",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-02 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Thursday",
"display_date": "2017-08-03",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-03",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-03 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Friday",
"display_date": "2017-08-04",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-04",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-04 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Saturday",
"display_date": "2017-08-05",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-05",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-05 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Sunday",
"display_date": "2017-08-06",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-06",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-06 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Monday",
"display_date": "2017-08-07",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-07",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-07 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Tuesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-08",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-08",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-08 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Wednesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-09",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-09",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-09 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Thursday",
"display_date": "2017-08-10",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-10",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-10 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Friday",
"display_date": "2017-08-11",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-11",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-11 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Saturday",
"display_date": "2017-08-12",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-12",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-12 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Sunday",
"display_date": "2017-08-13",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-13",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-13 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Monday",
"display_date": "2017-08-14",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-14",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-14 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Tuesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-15",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-15",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-15 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Wednesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-16",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-16",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-16 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Thursday",
"display_date": "2017-08-17",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-17",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-17 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Friday",
"display_date": "2017-08-18",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-18",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-18 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Saturday",
"display_date": "2017-08-19",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-19",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-19 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Sunday",
"display_date": "2017-08-20",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-20",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-20 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Monday",
"display_date": "2017-08-21",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-21",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-21 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Tuesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-22",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-22",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-22 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Wednesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-23",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-23",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-23 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Thursday",
"display_date": "2017-08-24",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-24",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-24 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Friday",
"display_date": "2017-08-25",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-25",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-25 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Saturday",
"display_date": "2017-08-26",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-26",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-26 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Sunday",
"display_date": "2017-08-27",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-27",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-27 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Monday",
"display_date": "2017-08-28",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-28",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-28 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Tuesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-29",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-29",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-29 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Wednesday",
"display_date": "2017-08-30",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-30",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-30 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
},
{
"display_weekday": "Thursday",
"display_date": "2017-08-31",
"starts_at_date": "2017-08-31",
"starts_at_time": "07:00",
"ends_at_date": "2017-08-31 17:00",
"ends_at_time": "17:00"
}
]
```

Now I just need to find all Timereports from current month and then in some way add those values to the correct days in the JSON object. But how?

Comment: This question is very fuzzy. You need to create a MVCE.

Comment: What are "all Timereports for the selected month"? if a Timereport has a `starts_at: "2017-07-31"` and `ends_at: "2017-08-04"` is that in the month of August or July (or both)? Also what would you display for "08-01", "08-02", "08-03" and "08-04"? Would they all get the same value?

Comment: I have updated now. I know how to get all Timereports for the current month but how can I use that data and put it into the correct days in the above (updated code).